# Не могу получить доступ к активити (Java android)

Tags: java, android

Я создал три активити. Каждый добавил в манифест. Но с одного активити я могу открыть третий активити, а со второго не могу. Приложение выдает ошибку. В чем может быть проблема? Команда вызова буквально была скопирована из первого активити во второй. Можете еще написать, как посмотреть причину ошибки приложения. Это тоже поможет

манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.unknown.kryptomessage">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activities.KryptoMain">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.Message"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.Settings"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.SendMail"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.km"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.au"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

способ вызова из первого активити (из KryptoMain):

```
public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_settings:
                intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;}}
```

способ вызова из Message:

```
Intent intent;
switch (view.getId()){
   case R.id.btn_settings:
        intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Покажите код манифеста и код вызова активити, отредактируйте своё сообщение, добавив туда код

Comment: Вы используете одну разметку на несколько активити? Почему у вас в двух разных активити R.id.btn_settings? В первом примере вы показали public void onClick(View v) и по этому v сделали вызов v.getId(), а во втором примере у вас нет кода обработчика и уже view.getId()

Answer (score 0):

измените `this` на `context` .И так же не лишнем было показать саму ошибку
А чтоб ее посмотреть просто нажмите на `Android Monitor` которая распалаегтся внизу студии   и в открывшемся окне выберите `Log Cat`  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]